# Designing a small footprint DC/DC converter

Tags: pcb-design, dc-dc-converter, feedback, ripple

This is my first time diving into DC/DC converters, so I'm learning a lot of new information and am aware that I may miss some important details. I'm hoping that others with more experience could point out and educate me about those, why they are crucial, and what they cause.

##### A little bit about the circuit

My input voltage is around 5V (I put 4.5 to 5.5V in the TI designer), with an output of a little over 3.3V. The expected load of the powered circuit is around 800mA, worst-case about 1.4A for a few minutes. For this purpose, I chose TI's [LM2831XMF/NOPB](https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=LM2831XMF/NOPB) (mostly because it was one of the only available 1.5A DC/DC converters I could find in stock near where I live due to chip shortage). I changed some of the components from the original "compact" design provided by TI's generator, like the inductor ([IHLP1212BZER3R3M11](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay/IHLP1212BZER3R3M11?qs=sGAEpiMZZMset%2FhoJ47xJBo%2Fl%2FbBddGIZ3yYO69CixA%3D)) and the "drain" diode ([SL04-HE3-08](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85942/sl04.pdf)), which should be decent replacements for the suggested parts.

##### The schematic

This is the schematic I came up with at the end:

[image: Schematic]

##### The PCB

The board I use has 4 layers. The red layer is the top layer, lower I have a ground layer followed by a VCC layer and the bottom layer. I try to provide a good ground for the output capacitor, diode and input capacitor (like suggested in the switching chip datasheet). I also put big pours as traces to reduce resistance between parts. Furthermore, I tried to reduce both fill and drain loops as much as possible, so this is the layout I came up with at the end:

[image: PCB]

Without copper pour for better visibility:

[image: No pour]

##### My existing concerns

What I'm worried about the most here is the feedback line, which I routed not that far from the inductor and could potentially cause output ripple. Would it be better to route it around the other side (to avoid the inductor more)? Doing that, I'm worried I'll make it into an even bigger antenna and worsen the situation. Do you perhaps have any suggestions on how to fix/deal with such an issue, or is it a non-issue as-is?

#### The solution:

[This is the final design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqZsj.jpg) (imgur.com) I'll use in production. I'll also update with some ripple data once I get the circuit and assemble the regulator.

Update: this design produces under somewhere around 5 mV of ripple, which should be good enough for most designs.

Comment: On our evaluation kits, we usually route the feedback trace on layer 4, with unbroken groundplane on layer 2 to help shield the feedback input from switching noise.

Comment: @MarkU Didn't think it's okay to route it through VIAs, as it passes multiple layers doing so (and they may act as additional antennas). Thank you for the suggestion, might go with that if nothing "cleaner" turns out to be the solution

Comment: Routing through vias is usually fine. The coupling between a plane and a wire perpendicular to that plane is very small. (note that via is not an acronym, and does not need to be capitalized!)

Comment: If you want a cooler layout more copper area is needed. TI suggests this https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgm87.png

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Where did you find that? Other than pouring a year worth of copper production on the board, that layout breaks just about every guideline from the their datasheet

Comment: I created this in a couple minute search on Webbench at TI tools, notice it only uses 2 layers fwiw @Maple  but it runs cooler and only 1 FB trace on bottom so it's cheap to build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SW copper pour sticks out too much beyond L1 pin. This does not improve current carrying capacity much but increases noise.

The footprints for capacitors look rather small. Did you cut the voltage rating too close?

But the biggest problem is that C7 is *way too far from GND pin of U1 and connected to it through two sets of VIAs*. I recommend moving it closer and connect via uninterrupted GND pour. Something like this, perhaps?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions - much appreciated. The input capacitor is rated at 35V, while the output capacitor is 6.3V (both in a 0603 package). Is this not enough? As for the vias, they look much smaller on your suggested design than what I have (12mil hole, 24mil pad). Would you suggest I reduce their size and put more of them to increase the total surface area of copper through the board?

Comment: The capacitor ratings are OK. The suggested design was made in 5 min with Photoshop only as an example of compact layout that follows all datasheet guidelines and optimizes traces. It can be used even with single layer PCB and it allows good thermal dissipation by either expanding GND and VIN zones or by stitching them to other layers right next to chip pins. But the component dimensions could be all wrong, so do not take it as an actual layout. I am also using 0.3mm VIAs, but I haven't done any comparative calculations. Don't think going under 0.2mm would be any better.

Comment: This is the design I derived from yours now: https://imgur.com/a/Q8H9WBs The only major difference is that there are a few more ground vias in the middle and that I put the output capacitor sideways to shorten some connections (could this perhaps cause issues when put near the inductor?)

Comment: Looks very good. I would push R8, C9 a bit down, and put D3 closer to the chip. You will lose 2 top VIAs , but the SW zone will be smaller and you can compensate by adding Vias next to Vin pin, since you passing Vin to another layer anyway, just further on the right. Also you can move C7 closer to SW pin.

Comment: One useful trick for maximizing heat dissipation is to draw all other zones with higher priority, then draw GND zone with lower priority and a bit of overlap. This way it will expand as much as configured clearance allows. But you seem to be doing exactly this already.

Comment: You can also extend GND from under the chip down and to the right, where "U1 R9" silkscreen is. This will give you another 3-4 thermal VIAs. Finally, I maybe nitpicking here, but that R9 pull-up changes signal function from "enable" to "shutdown". Renaming the net may help avoiding confusion later.

Comment: You probably meant R9 and C8 since that would allow me to bring D3 further down. I'll leave the enable net named that way since it reflects the pin names. The converter with the additional suggestions now looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/qyndCOc

Comment: Well, IMHO that is about perfect and as compact as it can possibly be. You DRC may complain about overlapping courtyards, but those seem to be too generous in your footprint library to begin with. If you look at Pololu [modules](https://www.pololu.com/category/247/d36v6x-step-down-voltage-regulators), for example, you'd see they use even tighter clearances. Oh, and why don't you update the question with the final design. Someone coming here later might find it useful

Comment: Also, check your inductor footprint. The pads seem to be quite different from suggested in IHLP1212BZER3R3M11 datasheet

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't complain luckily. I will update the question once I'm finished designing it. Thank you for pointing out to footprint - the one I have might be okay, but I'll make one from the datasheet just to be sure.

Comment: I added the design to the question. As for the footprint, I extended the recommended pads about 0.5mm outwards for easier hand soldering. Do you think this is too much and would just pick up more noise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131831/discussion-between-maple-and-mysterious-wolf).